# convert oracle scripts in compatible with HSQLDB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a spring project using Hibernate. For dev I am using oracle as a database. But for testing purpose I am using HSQLDB. 
I have SQL scripts which are compatible with oracle. I want to convert those scripts compatible with HSQLDB and load the HSQLDB with those scripts to run all test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If your existing tables in Oracle are generated by Hibernate , you can just simply change `hibernate.dialect` property to `HSQLDB` dialect (i.e `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` ) and then set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update` or `create` . Then , Hibernate will automatically create the tables in the HSQLDB during its start-up.